# Using the Argument Principle, evaluate $\int_{|z|=4}\frac{2z\sin(z)+z^2\cos(z)}{z^2\sin(z)}dz$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Using the Argument Principle, evaluate
$$\int_{|z|=4}\frac{2z\sin(z)+z^2\cos(z)}{z^2\sin(z)}dz$$

The argument principle is the idea that $$\int_\Gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=2\pi i(N-P)$$ where N is the number of zeros where N is the number of zeros of $f$ on $\Gamma$ and P is the number of poles of $f$ on $\Gamma$.

I was hoping someone could double check my work.

I think that $N=3$ and $P=0$, so $2\pi i(3-0)=6\pi i$. Is this correct? A classmate of mine got $10\pi i$, so I'm trying to get some thoughts on my solution.

Comment: Why do you say there are no poles?

Comment: @saulspatz: It's about the poles of $f$, not those of $f'/f$. And $f(z)=z^2\sin z$ has no poles.

Comment: @complexanalysis: You have to count the multiplicity of the poles and zeroes as well. The zero at $z=0$ has higher multiplicity than those at $z=\pm\pi$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Yes, you're right.  Brain cramp.